# Of what school of graphic design are 18th - 19th century illustrations?

Tags: illustration

Particularly interested in the illustrations of Alesha Sivartha

http://www.wired.com/table_of_malcontents/2006/11/with_what_we_do/

For example, would you say they are Victorian, or Edwardian, or something else?  I'm trying to put together a design concept for a website and am finding it difficult to speak about.

Comment: They were strictly old school. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Victorian Engraving is a usable label. A few years ago there was a resurgence of this in digital form, for which Victorian Engraving-style was an apt moniker.

I've also seen it referred to as Industrial age engravings.

Comment: Thanks - I know this could easily have been too open ended for this site's intentions, so I appreciate you guys answering anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is, Victorian and Edwardian refer to specific time periods: they coincide with the reign of an English/British Monarch. This clearly marks them as British, but they are exclusionary terms.

The secondary problem is that those periods span multiple style movements. There is a huge stylistic gulf between prints and *especially* illustration of the 1930s and the 1950s (for example). Even more so between a print from 1780 and a print from 1850, since the technology gap is probably greater between those years than the 1930s-1950s.

As someone who has worked in this field for many years, it is more typical to say "mid-nineteenth-century British engraving." This happens to be ridiculously boring to style from a graphic design perspective however.

Classification starts with either time period and then nationality, or nationality then time period.

The alternative is to be specific about the movement: "Romantic", "Pre-Raphaelite", "Art Nouveau" etc.

Comment: Yeah - I wasn't very specific in my question.  Thanks for your feedback nonetheless.